# Remount writable by all users?

Tags: shell, mount, partitions, busybox

I want to remount a read-only partition in read-write mode, but I want it to be writable for all users.

So far I've got this:

```
mount -o bind /someplace /someplace_else
mount -o remount rw /someplace_else
```

The first command creates a new mount point from a directory. The second one remounts the new mount point as rewritable. This all works.

Problem is, the new mount point has uid=1000,fmask=0222,dmask=0222, so the non-root user still can't write anything, and root can't give it permission.

How do I change the fmask and uid when remounting, or is there something else I can do to make the mount writable for the normal user?

Also, note that the command that worked for me is this:

```
mount -o remount rw /someplace_else
```

...with no comma between "remount" and "rw," as I've seen in almost everything my searches turned up. Does anyone know anything about this discrepancy in syntax?

**Update**

Ok, I guess had a strange version of mount. Now I'm using busybox mount, and I can do this:

```
busybox mount -o remount,rw /someplace_else
```

It accepts this version of the command, but the masks don't change:

```
busybox mount -o remount,rw,fmask=0000,dmask=0000 /someplace_else
```

Storage is vfat, maybe that has something to do with it?

`suid` and `dev` options also work, but the fmask and dmask won't change (I want them 000, that should leave files with 777).

Comment: I don't know whether this qualifies as a dev question or not, I guess it's a bit technical. Mods, if you think this is in the wrong place, feel free to migrate it elsewhere in SE.

Comment: fmask and dmask would be passed to the mount. it would look something like: mount -o fmask=0777,dmask=0777 remount rw /someplace_else

Comment: @RyanConrad, I know, but it's not working. I had some weird version of mount. Making an update.